# Database table for bus booking website

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I'm creating a bus booking website using Django. I'm stuck at what the database tables should look like. So far I've created the displayed tables, I'm very poor with databases so please mention foreign keys and primary keys when answering. Also, I'm stuck on how to actually book seats in Django, like what will be the code in the background and what other packages should I use. Thanks.

---

Table- Route:
 Columns - route_id (primary key), 
          location_from, 
          location_to, 
          route_name,

Table - Bus:
Columns - Bus_id(primary key), type_of_bus,
    bus_registration, 
    capacity,
    bus_number,
    route (foreign key)

Also I'm using the default sqlite database that comes with django. Is it good enough to build this kind of website or do I need to change? This website is just a project and will never go into production phase.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend writing your database schema in Python classes (as Django models) and then using `./manage.py makemigrations ./manage.py migrate`, which will look at your model code and create the corresponding database schema. [This portion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/) of the django tutorial could be helpful to you.

The python code corresponding to your example for a route would look something like:

from django.db import models

```
class Route(models.model):
    location_from=models.CharField()
    location_to=models.CharField()
    route_name=models.CharField()
```

This is a much easier way to write a database schema, especially if you're not so hot with databases.

If your app will never be in production, SQLite is fine - it's very similar to other database engines for toy projects.

As for what your data model should look like, I think it depends how complex you want to make the app. For a start, I think you could add a `Location` model, which your `Route` model should reference. For making reservations, you could look into [django booking](https://github.com/bitlabstudio/django-booking) - I haven't used it but it comes up on django packages when you search 'booking'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to create models and how to migrate them. I know how to use Django. I was asking what the tables should look like and if there are any libraries or packages that might be helpful in building this kind of "booking" website. Anyway thanks for your help.